# Laravel: Using belongsTo() add unexpected attributes to my Model

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm writing a REST API using Lumen. I have for my example 2 models `User` and `Post`. `Post` model use the method `belongsTo` to get the `User` model which created this post. My goal was to define an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) so I can get the author's username of the post just like that `Post::find($id)->author`. So according to the doc I do this:

*Post.php :*

```php
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'posts';
  protected $appends = ['author'];

  protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description'
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
    'user_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
  ];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
  }

  public function getAuthorAttribute()
  {
    return $this->user->username;
  }
}
```

Now the getter works well and I can easily get the author of the given `Post`.

But if I tried to return the `Post` in a JSON response, it's also return me weird attributes like `user` that seems to come from my `user()` method that call a `belongsTo()`:

```php
return response()->json(Post::find(2), 200);
```

```js
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Amazing Post",
    "description": "Nice post",
    "author": "FooBar",
    "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "username": "FooBar"
    }
}
```

If I use the `attributesToArray()` it's work as expected:

```php
return response()->json(Post::find(2)->attributesToArray(), 200);
```

```js
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Amazing Post",
    "description": "Nice post",
    "author": "FooBar"
}
```

Moreover if I remove the getter `getAuthorAttribute()` and the `$appends` declaration, I don't get the unexpected `user` attribute.

But I don't want to use this method each time and it doesn't make it work if I want to return all my `Post` using:

```php
return response()->json(Post::all(), 200);
```

Have someone an idea why I get this additional attribute using `belongsTo`?

Comment: You can unset pre-loaded relations like this: `$post->unsetRelation('user')`. 
But getAuthorAttribute() will load that again. So i think there is no straightforward way for what you want.

Comment: @AminShojaei If I remove the `$appends` declaration and the `getAuthorAttribute()` getter, I get the normal behaviour (just without `author`) without the `user` attribute. So are you sure that's a normal behaviour?

Comment: No that's not the case. `getAuthorAttribute()` is fine. My suggestion is to use collection `map()` method. 
like this: 

`return Post::all()->map(function($p){ return [ 'title' => $p->title, 'author' => $p->author ] })`

Comment: @AminShojaei What I want is customized attributes. This is the work of laravel's [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). I don't want to manipulate my Model output each time that I have to return something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This behavior is because of performance. 
  When you call `$post->user` for first time, The Laravel read it from the database and **keep it in `$post->relation[]` for next usage**. So next time Laravel can read it from the array and prevent from executing a query again(it will be useful if you use it in multiple places).
- Plus, the user is also an attribute and the Laravel merges 
  `$attributes` and `$relations` array together when you call `$model->toJson()` or `$model->toArray()`

> The Laravel's Model source code:
>
> ```
> public function toArray()
> {
>     return array_merge($this->attributesToArray(), $this->relationsToArray());
> }
>
> public function jsonSerialize()
> {
>     return $this->toArray();
> }
> ```

Comment: Ok well it will hidde the `user` attribute. But there's still one unexpected attribute that come out of nowhere just because I make a `belongsTo()`. My goal with this question is to find why this behaviour, not to get a hacky workaround. But I really thanks you for your time and your efforts ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry. i thought you're looking for a solution. I edited my answer for you @johannchopin

Comment: Mmmh well I see and have you an idea how I can retrieve just the attributes without the relations using `::all()`?

Comment: The thing is when you return  Post::all(), the Laravel will call the `toJson()` automatically on each instance. So you have at least two options: 1.override the `toJson()` method inside your Post model 2. use collection `map()` method and call `attributesToArray()` inside of it.

Comment: Using the second option with `map()` work like a charm. Is there any performance issue with this approach?

Comment: @johannchopin I don't see any performance issue. because if you don't do that, the Laravel will do it. Keep is mind, when you return collection of Models, **somebody has to do** some map-like process on them and convert them to simple array.

Comment: But what I do is `Post::all()->map( ... )` which is redundant isn't it?

Comment: It may seems like that, but it isn't. The result of `all()` is a collection of `Posts`. But result of map is a collection of arrays, so that's not redundant. (Checkout the `Illuminate\Support\Traits\EnumeratesValues.php` file, line 727)

Comment: Thanks you a lot man ;) very clear explanation and I will adopt your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach was good, you just need to add 'user' into the $hidden array

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'posts';
  protected $appends = ['author'];

  protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'description'
  ];

  protected $hidden = [
    'user_id',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'user', // <-- add 'user' here
  ];

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
  }

  public function getAuthorAttribute()
  {
    return $this->user->username;
  }
}
```

And your resulting model would be:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Amazing Post",
  "description": "Nice post",
  "author": "FooBar"
}
```